# While Loop in PHP for my beginners class online

Tags: php

first time to post and brand new to developing/coding. I'm currently in an inline php class for school and had this section in one of my labs that Iwasnt sure how to properly express:

Use a while loop to show the prices:Reverse the value of the downloads variable (i.e. set it to true if it is false or false if it is true). 
Use a counter starting at 1 and ending with 6
Calculate the price using the counter as the quantity and a price of 12.99 if the download variable is false or 9.99 if it is true
If the download variable is false, add the shipping cost to the total
Write out the quantity and total for each iteration.

Comment: please post you code what you have already tried

Comment: This looks like a fragment of something, and if we dont have the format these variables are in its hard to help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? we can't code from scratch for you, and re-format your question so it is easy to read.

Comment: Here is the documentation on while loops: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping.asp  If you're taking the class, it's my assumption that you're trying to learn; therefore I recommend reading the class material and doing couple google searches.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to try to solve your own problem first. Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this ?

```
<?php

$total  = 0;

for ($i=1; $i <=6 ; $i++) {

    $quantity   = $i;  // using counter as quantity

    $download   = ( $i%2 ) ? true : false; // Reverse the value of the downloads variable

    if ( $download ) {  // switch price
        $price = 12.99;
    }else{
        $price = 9.99;
    }

    $total += ( $quantity * $price );
}

$shipping_cost = 20; // for example
echo '<h4>shipping cost:'.$shipping_cost.'</h4>';

$total_with_shipping = $total + $shipping_cost;
echo '<h4>total with shipping:'.$total_with_shipping.'</h4>';

 ?>
```